# How to network a docker container manually

Tags: docker

I have two docker containers:

- a container started via `docker-compose` that runs a PostgreSQL server that is accessible on the host machine via port `5432`
- a container started via `docker run` that wants to access that PostgresQL

Running the following:

```
docker run -p 80:80 a609c83f4cc3
```

successfully starts the container, but it's not able to access the PostgreSQL server.

```
12:16:06.192 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.2150.0>) failed to connect: ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
```

Is there a way to network the container running via `docker run` manually so that it's able to connect to the PostgreSQL server?

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: pass
      POSTGRES_DB: database
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose will on its own create a network named `default`.  Like other Docker objects, this is prefixed with the Compose "project name", usually the current directory name.  If you run `docker network ls` you should see a network named `something_default`.

Once you have that network name, you can supply it to `docker run`:

```
docker run --net something_default -p 80:80 a609c83f4cc3
```

You will also have to configure your application to connect to the database container; it will not be on `localhost`.  The standalone container should still be able to use the names that Compose provides, so for example it can use the Compose service name `db` as a hostname with the standard PostgreSQL port 5432 (`ports:` are ignored if present).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a network with this command:

```
docker network create network_name
```

then run your container with `--network network_name` option.

You can also add this network in your `docker-compose.yml`.

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the Compose networking setup further.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options basically,

**Option 1:**
If you are not familiar with docker network commands, you can simply deploy Portainer as a container management tool with a very user friendly UI and withing which you can change to which network a container is attached.

**Option 2**
You need to attach your first container to the network created by your docker-compose.yml

fist of all insepct your postgres container and determine the network

```
docker container inspect <postgres_container> | grep Network
```

then attach your first container to the same network

```
docker network connect <network_name/id> <first_container_name/id>
```

then restart your first container

```
docker container restart <first_container_name>
```